# What is the `_container` property of Django's http.response?

Tags: django, http, pdf, django-rest-framework

I can't find one good source that actually tries to explain it. The top 5 search results are just different links to source code. Right now, I'm trying to read a PDF that is being returned from a `GET` request, and I want to know why it's in `response._container`, when response is type `HttpResponse`. Is this PDF even what I'm looking for? Why is it the second element in the `_container` list?

Comment: a list of properly encoded bytestrings to support `write()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firts point, this is not a "property" but an "attribute" - in Python, "property" is [a builtin type implementing generic computed attribute support](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties), and `HttpResponse._container` is actually used as implementation support for the `HttpResponse.content` property.

So this an implementation detail (as you can tell by the single leading underscore), and hence not documented indeed (a package or framework's documentation only concerns the API, not the implementation). IOW, the best documentation here is the source code. FWIW, the source code is always the ultimate documentation, even if not always the most user-friendly ;-)

Hopefully, this part is quite easy to understand (code from the current master branch, but this part is quite stable):

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L308

```
class HttpResponse(HttpResponseBase):

    # ....


    @property
    def content(self):
        return b''.join(self._container)

    @content.setter
    def content(self, value):
        # Consume iterators upon assignment to allow repeated iteration.
        if hasattr(value, '__iter__') and not isinstance(value, (bytes, str)):
            content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(chunk) for chunk in value)
            if hasattr(value, 'close'):
                try:
                    value.close()
                except Exception:
                    pass
        else:
            content = self.make_bytes(value)
        # Create a list of properly encoded bytestrings to support write().
        self._container = [content]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._container)

    def write(self, content):
        self._container.append(self.make_bytes(content))

    # ...

    def writelines(self, lines):
        for line in lines:
            self.write(line)
```

As you can see, the response's content is exposed as the (read/write) `content` property, but is actually stored in the `_container` attribute. This is used to 1/ make sure the content is stored in the expected format, 2/ allow support for the `response.write()` and `iter(response)` operations.

Two points bout the use of a list here:

1/ using a list to dynamically build strings is a pretty common Python idiom - adding to a list and joining it in the end is usually faster than concatenating strings

2/ this also allow to make the `HttpResponse` object a "file-like" object - HttpResponse has similar `close`, `write`, `writelines`, `flush`, `tell` and `__iter__` operations.

> Why is it the second element in the _container list?

Probably because it's been written as the second element.